# Use exprotobuf to deal with Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: elixir, protocol-buffers

Anybody is familiar with [exprobuf](https://github.com/bitwalker/exprotobuf) ? I've got an incorrect encoding result, here is the detail [issue](https://github.com/bitwalker/exprotobuf/issues/75).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expect to got `<08 96 01>`, but got `<8, 150, 1>` instead. Did I missed something?

They are the same. One is in hexadecimal, one is in decimal. Hex 96 is decimal 150. It is very common to express binary output in hex because it is terse (at most 2 chars per byte) and case insensitive - and as such most binary editors / viewers use hex.